# Vba code for hide and unhide rows by using a checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo79K.jpg) {SOLVED by TOM- please refer ActiveX control} I have two buttons ( button 1   & button 2)   to hide and unhide  row contains a specific word “petroleum”  in another sheets of workbook ( if  I click button 1 all the rows contains “petroleum”  will hide , and if I click button 2 then all the rows contains “petroleum”  will unhide)

My doubt is,  can I use  ONE check box  instead of  TWO button to run this vba code  ( the idea is if I checkedin  the  checkbox the row should hide and unhide if the checkbox is unchecked .

"for row hide "

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sht In Worksheets
    beginRow = 2
    endRow = 1000
    chkCol = 12
    For RowCnt = beginRow To endRow
        If sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).Value = "Petroleum" Then
            sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True

        End If
    Next RowCnt
Next sht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

"For row unhide"

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sht In Worksheets
    beginRow = 2
    endRow = 1000
    chkCol = 12
    For RowCnt = beginRow To endRow
        If sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).Value = "Petroleum" Then
            sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        End If
    Next RowCnt
Next sht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

'As advised  by Tom i have revised the code as per below (this is working for me)

```
Private Sub CheckBox13_Click()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        beginRow = 2
        endRow = 1000
        chkCol = 12
        For RowCnt = beginRow To endRow
            If sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).Value = "Petroleum" Then

                sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = CheckBox13.Value
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are these Forms controls, as opposed to ActiveX? Anyway you can, just check if the box is ticked or not, they are your two states.

Comment: SJR ..updated my question with a screen  shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Form controls you could do it with one button using the following

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim chkBox As CheckBox

    Set chkBox = Application.Caller

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        beginRow = 2
        endRow = 1000
        chkCol = 12
        For RowCnt = beginRow To endRow
            If sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).Value = "Petroleum" Then
                sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(chkBox.Value = 1, True, False)
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For ActiveX similarly you could do it with

```
Private Sub CheckBox13_Click()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        beginRow = 2
        endRow = 1000
        chkCol = 12
        For RowCnt = beginRow To endRow
            If sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).Value = "Petroleum" Then

                sht.Cells(RowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = CheckBox13.Value
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response , i  have  created a module and then linked  with a checkbox button in excel sheet , ( if i use  two button then the VBA running perfectly for hiding and unhiding. i am trying to run the code with  checkbox ( the reason for trying with checkbox is if i place button i dont have any idea about which button i have clicked .

Comment: @RamPrasanth I'm not entirely sure what your issue with the my answered code is

Comment: sorry i didn't give a detailed information .... i have 2 excel sheet ( Scope filter  and Heatth and safety).. i  would like to set a checkbox in scope filter . if i checked the checkbox then in sheet heath and safety the specific word "Petroleum " to be hided ... if i uncheck the checkbox then i has to unhide the specific word "Petroleum " . i have used the code you have provided it shows some error ( please refer the photo attached to my question)

Comment: @RamPrasanth Just seen how you are trying to set the `Set ChkBox` line it should just be `Set ChkBox = Application.Caller` no need for modification.

Comment: i tried but it shows "runtime error 424 object required".. how to come out from this

Comment: @RamPrasanth Are you using `ActiveX` or `Form Controls`? I suspect you're mixing the two

Comment: i have used  check box button from form controls  , i dont have any idea about this . ( for this Vba what type of control we should use )

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you use you just need to use the correct syntax for that one. For a form control you should use my `Button1_Click` code. Make sure that the button is running this macro by right clicking on it -> Assign Macro -> Select the macro. It concerns me that you've declared it as `Private` and is suggesting to me that you're using it in the `Sheet` object instead.

Comment: Yes.. now the Vba code running correctly  thanks for your valuable support....but when i am unchecking its not unhiding the specific word "Petroleum" ( not returning to the actual state)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the onclick event on the checkbox, like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
       ' hide rows
    Else
        ' unhide rows
    End If
End Sub
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, as advised i have modified the code but it shows  Run Time Error '424' object required

Comment: You need to create a checkbox, you can follow this guide: https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/excel-userform/checkbox/

Comment: replace CheckBox1 by the name of your checkbox

Comment: some issues after clicking the checkbox 13 , i have added a picture in my question